# Owner Name and Region return undefined - Discord v13

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So as of now... I can only seem to get the server owners Id with the `guild.ownerId` string, how can I go about getting the owners username or tag as well? and how to fix the region returning undefined?

```js
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");
const config = require("../../botconfig");

module.exports = {
    name: "serverinfo",
    aliases: ["si", "server-info", "server-Info"],
    description: "Shows info on a server!",
    usage: `serverinfo`,
  run: async (client, message, args) => {
    const inline = true;
          
    let members = message.guild.memberCount;
    
    const siEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
    .setAuthor(message.guild.name, message.guild.iconURL())
    .setThumbnail(message.guild.iconURL())
    .addField("Server Created", `<t:${~~(message.channel.guild.createdAt / 1000)}:R>`, true)
    .addField("Server Owner", `• \`${message.guild.owner} (${message.guild.ownerId})\``, inline)
    .addField("Region", `• \`${message.guild.region}\``, inline)
    .addField("Total Members", `• \`${members.toLocaleString()}\``, inline)
    .addField("Text Channels", `• \`${message.guild.channels.cache.size}\``, inline)
    .addField("Voice Channels", `• \`${message.guild.channels.cache.filter(ch => ch.type === "voice").size}\``, inline)
    .addField("Total Roles", `• \`${message.guild.roles.cache.size}\``, inline)
    .setColor("#FFA500")
    .setFooter(`Server ID: ${message.guild.id}`)
    .setTimestamp()

    message.reply({ embeds: [siEmbed] });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get server owner in djs v13 you need to use [`guild.fetchOwner()`](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v13.html#guild-owner) method:

```js
let owner = await message.guild.fetchOwner()
console.log(owner)
```

Comment: That worked, but it is trying to mention the owner, and i don't really want it to do that.. how can i go about it just displaying the owners username instead?

Comment: You can get the username from `owner.username`